# decrease the height of each element in the list of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

[image]
i am a beginner to android i tried in please help
my code is

```
     <AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/receipt_account_name" >
```

i tried with android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp", android:dropDownHeight="5dp", android:height="5dp",  android:layout_height="5dp" etc. No font size is defined.

in java class 
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);

please help.

Comment: please reduce listview width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create your own xml like this

layout/item.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"/>
```

then try following

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(this, R.layout.item,R.id.text1, COUNTRIES);
```

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView  to TextView is it possible?

Comment: no.. autocompletetextview would be there. No need to change other code.

Comment: output shows size of the AutoCompleteTextView  is 5dp not the height of the list. in shot selected item ll not be visible.does "new ArrayAdapter<T>" means "new ArrayAdapter<String>"

Comment: increase textview height to 15dp